# Appcerator module in Xcode and using simple .wav files

Tags: ios, xcode, appcelerator

I have an appcelerator module written in Xcode. Everything works, except it throws an error when I try to play a sound file. The code works in Xcode in a standalone app, but not as a module in appcelerator. I am not sure if the sound file is simply not building into the module, or if I have to change the path to something else. Where is the best place to store the sound files? Do I need to adjust the path? Please assist. Below is the playSound method that causes the error.

```
-(void)playSound:(NSString*)fileName
{
     NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:@"wav"];
     NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
     _audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL error:&error];
     [_audioPlayer play];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the module you have used in xcode doesnt work in appcelerator. Rather you can get sound file from below code. Hope it helps.

```
var player = Ti.Media.createSound({url:"sound.wav"});
player.play();
```

Comment: The module itself works fine. I just want to be able to play a sound file from within the module, but it throws an error every time. I assume it has to do with the sound file not being in the main bundle.